# How to send the a return object in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I´m trying to create a function that make a request to a website and, as the return of the function, I want to deliver the object "BODY" created by the request. But everytime I have "Object undefined" return.

What I need to change in order to deliver this result ?

Here are the code:

```
// ---- Funções --------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
 function consultaCep(cep){ 
   request(`https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`, {json: true}, (err, res2, body) => {
   if(err)  return console.log(`Erro na consulta: ${err}`)
   return body;

  });

 }

 // Rotas ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//

app.get('/', (req,res)=> {
  x = consultaCep('13085485');
  console.log(x);
  res.end(x);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to wait until the request is completed.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. You can use a callback.

You can pass a callback to the method that invokes the web request, and invoke that callback from within that method:

```js
var consultaCep = function(callback){
  request('https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/', function (error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      status = "succeeded";
      callback(null, {status : status});
    } else {
      callback(error);
    }
  })
}


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  consultaCep(function(err, result){
    if(err){
      res.send(500, { error: 'Something went wrong' });
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});
```